# How to retreive all the genes belonging to one GO term

Tags: r

I'd like to retreive all the genes belonging to a GO term.

I tried (in R):

```
library(org.Hs.eg.db)

xx <- as.list(org.Hs.egGO2ALLEGS)
```

`xx` is a list of GO terms, and for each GO term there's a list of the corresponding genes with an "entrezID" format.

The problem is that when I check this output on other databases (GeneCards, etc...) I can't find the same results and correspondence between the genes and the GO term that I found with `org.Hs.eg.db`.

Do you know a better way? Am I missing something here?

Comment: yes it's correct. how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: for example, the first GO term given by org.Hs.eg.db is "GO:0000002". The first gene in the list for this GO term is "142" which is "PARP1". PARP1 is not given as being part of this GO term in Amigo2 for instance or GeneCards.

Comment: you have to check what type of GO terms the websites are displaying, for example genecard will display only molecular function go terms and also certain evidences. This is not a programming problem. I suggest you post this on biostars if you still cannot resolve this

Comment: Which version of Bioconductor are you using? This will likely explain the difference. Also, not sure how frequent does GeneCard update their GO annotation or where do they take it from (It doesn't appear on the list of sources https://www.genecards.org/Guide/Sources)